# Update form in rails - No route matches [PUT]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, routes, insert-update

I have a form to create adverts.

Controllers:

```
  def edit
    @engines = Engine.all
    @car = Car.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @car = Car.find(params[:id])

    if @car.save
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

My routes:

```
resources :adverts
```

Create.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @car, :url => adverts_path do |f| %>

  <div><%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %></div>

  <%= hidden_field_tag :model_id, params[:model_id] %>

  <%= select_tag :engine_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@engines, "id", "name",:selected=>@car.engine_id) %>

  <div><%= f.submit "Create car!" %></div>
<% end %>
```

I can create advert, but I can't to update it.

edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @car, :url => adverts_path do |f| %>

  <div><%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %></div>

  <%= hidden_field_tag :model_id, params[:model_id] %>

  <%= select_tag :engine_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@engines, "id", "name",:selected=>@car.engine_id) %>

  <div><%= f.submit "Update car!" %></div>
<% end %>
```

when I submited my form, I have an error - **No route matches [PUT] "/adverts"**

$ rake routes:

```
                       adverts GET    /adverts(.:format)                     adverts#index
                               POST   /adverts(.:format)                     adverts#create
                    new_advert GET    /adverts/new(.:format)                 adverts#new
                   edit_advert GET    /adverts/:id/edit(.:format)            adverts#edit
                        advert GET    /adverts/:id(.:format)                 adverts#show
                               PUT    /adverts/:id(.:format)                 adverts#update
                               DELETE /adverts/:id(.:format)                 adverts#destroy
```

I need help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you are updating you have to let Rails know which object you want to update by passing an `id`.

In `edit.html.erb` change:

```
<%= form_for @car, :url => adverts_path do |f| %>
```

to:

```
<%= form_for @car, :url => advert_path(@car) do |f| %>
```

By the way, I find your code very strange. Why don't your model names match your controllers and routes? I mean you are creating an advert but your model is called car. That doesn't make any sense. Either call it car or advert, but don't mix them.

Comment: Tryed, for example - No route matches [PUT] "/adverts.38"

Comment: @StackStack, does it work if you try `advert_path(@car)` instead of `adverts_path(@car)`?

Comment: I have a front, which used Cars controller to show cars. And now I create an adverts controller to save, edit and show private user cars.

Comment: @Stack, glad it works. Also check out Kien Thanh's answer because your update action doesn't save any changes.

Comment: @Mischa -> I know this is a very old thread, but I'll ask anyway: why does advert_path(@car) work but not adverts_path(@car) ?

Comment: @orrymr Because that's the helper Rails generates when using `resources`. It makes sense, because you're updating a single advert, not multiple. When you run `rake routes` you can see which `_path` and `_url` helpers are available.

Answer (score 4):

If you used RESTful routing, you don't need to specify a `url`, just need:

```
<%= form_for @car do |f| %>
```

The form can know `@car` is new record, or saved record, so it will send appropriate http method.

And in your update action:

```
def update
  @car = Car.find(params[:id])

  if @car.update_attributes(params[:car])
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what he should be doing. (See the remark at the bottom of my answer.) But because of the discrepancy between `Car` and `Advert` this won't work. This will do a put request to `cars/:id`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: @Mischa yeah, I saw, but I still think he should use `update_attributes` instead of `save` :)

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. With his current controller code no changes are saved at all. I missed that. +1

Comment: I believe it should be `<%= form_for @car do |f| %>` instead of `<%= form_for @car |f| %>` in Rails 4. [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for)

Answer (score 0):

I got myself in a similar situation today with a mismatched resource and model name. I agree the model and controller names need to correlate, but you can override the routes name to be whatever you want.

```
resources :cars, path: "adverts"
```

Along with RESTful routing

```
<%= form_for @car do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to make sure your `url:` path is **singular** on the `@form_form`.